# TransientPropertyValueException after saving parent with an created child

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Let´s say I have this hibernate relationships.

```
 class A{
   @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false)
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @XmlElement
   private B b;
}
```

And this other

```
class B{  
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
   @Getter @Setter
   @XmlTransient
   private A a;

  }
```

In some point I want to Save my class A, is the first time so does not exist on database yet, "but" B already exist because was saved in another transaction before but not On Cascade by A, so the relationship with A on the B table still is null. Now with this current configuration I´m receiving this exception.

```
      org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

So, what configuration on A I have to do in order to persist A, and put in B the relationship with A?.

Regards.

Comment: For `OneToOne` bidirectional mapping, `@JoinColumn` should include at owner side only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you mapped your association twice. If B is the owner side than you need to mark the other end with mappedBy:

```
class A{
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="a", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})   
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @XmlElement
   private B b;
}
```

Then this is the step-by-step order of operations:

1. You need to fetch B first

   ```
   B b session.get(B.class, 1L);
   ```
2. You create A

   ```
   A a = new A();
   ```
3. You set both sides of the association

   ```
   a.b = b;
   b.a = a;
   ```
4. You persist a

   ```
   session.persist(a);
   ```

Comment: Is what I´m doing and nothing, same error. And I try just with MERGE and DELETE cascade types but still sam error

Comment: I see that you haven't used mappedBy for one of the associations. Check my updated response.